# Amazon Sales Channel extension for Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, sales, amazon

Does the Amazon Sales Channel extension version 4.1 work on Magento 2.3.3? It doesn't seem to. I installed the extension per the documenation, added the Production API Key from my Magento Marketplace account to the System and when I go to `Marketing -> Channels -> Amazon` I get the error `Unexpected network error  "please try again later"`.

Further inspection in the console shows the error: `Error: GraphQL error: Internal server error`

And when I click on Add Amazon Store it pops a window saying: `Connection error Unable to create a new store. Please try again later`.

**I'm on Magento 2.3.3 with PHP 7.1.33**

Comment: did you find any solutions?

Comment: @Casey Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Getting issue, of js. Because of which amazon sales channel dashboard not loading. Issue is coming on only production server.